# CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am applying various filters on canvas in my application. It works perfectly fine on all browsers and devices except Safari on IOS. I also realized that the API is not supported on Safari, but I have to implement the filters somehow. Any help would be appreciated. This is the code for the filters.

```
if (filter === "brownie"){
          ctx.filter = 'hue-rotate(25deg)';
        } else if (filter === "grayscale"){
          ctx.filter = 'grayscale(.8) contrast(100%)';
        }else if (filter === "vintage"){
          ctx.filter = 'hue-rotate(45deg) contrast(100%)';
        }else if (filter === "technicolor"){
          ctx.filter = 'hue-rotate(340deg) contrast(100%)';
        }else if (filter === "polaroid"){
          ctx.filter = 'brightness(135%) contrast(100%)';
        }else if (filter === "polaroid"){
          ctx.filter = 'hue-rotate(30deg) contrast(100%)';
        }else if (filter === "bw"){
          ctx.filter = 'grayscale(.6) contrast(30%)';
        } else{
          ctx.filter = "contrast(100%)"
```

Also, I used the polyfill https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill
however, it does not seem to work. It is generating the following warning when I am adding objects to canvas. I am like not even applying the filters when this is happening

```
Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (384 MB)
```

I tried to solve it but no luck :(

Comment: You can try using css filters instead